# How to switch an instance in Oracle 12c when the same database is connected to 2 instances

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Click the lines in blue for the images.

Following is the listener status which shows service 'orcl' having 2 instances i.e. 'florcl' and 'orcl' in Oracle 12c out of which 'orcl' is READY and 'florcl' is BLOCKED

[image: Following is the listener status which shows service 'orcl' having 2 instances i.e. 'florcl' and 'orcl' in Oracle 12c out of which 'orcl' is READY and 'florcl' is BLOCKED]

Now, when I connect to the database using `sqlplus / as sysdba` and select the instance name, it shows florcl only

Instance name is shown as florcl

[image: Instance name is shown as florcl]

I want to connect to the database using 'orcl' instance. When I try to connect the database using 'conn username/password' command I get the following error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
```

This might be due to the fact that the instance (florcl) with which the database is connected is BLOCKED. 
How do I switch to the other instance (orcl) which is READY?

Answer (score -1):

Check your  network configuration files to make sure they are present 
Then do lsnctl start
Then set your environment to orcl 
Then log in as sysdba 
You do the same for florcl